# Swift Load image from url with combining strings

Tags: ios, string, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have working codes with detailTitle, detailDesc strings but my  detailImage string not showing my UIImage. My codes under.

**ViewController** Here coming my strings to DetailView Controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let subcatVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Detail") as! DetailViewController
    subcatVC.detailTitle = self.arrayCategory[indexPath.row][API_PARAM_CAT_NAME] as! String
    subcatVC.detailDesc = self.arrayCategory[indexPath.row][API_PARAM_DESC_NAME] as! String
    subcatVC.detailImage = self.arrayCategory[indexPath.row][API_PARAM_CAT_IMAGE] as! String
    _ = UINavigationController(rootViewController: subcatVC)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subcatVC, animated: false)

    NSLog("%@", self.arrayCategory[indexPath.row][API_PARAM_CAT_IMAGE] as! String);

}
```

**DetailViewController**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var detailTitle:String?
    var detailDesc:String?
    var detailImage:String?




    @IBOutlet weak var textim: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textbig: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imagetbig: UIImageView!


override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textbig.text = detailDesc
    textim.text = detailTitle


    if let url = detailImage {
        load_image(url)
    }


func load_image(urlString:String)
{




    let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil && data != nil)
        {
            func display_image()
            {
                self.imagetbig.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

**I need ;**

Top codes working good but don't show image so i need to combining strings for my full image url.

```
NSLog("%@",detailImage)  Output =  23423434.jpg
```

My base url string :

```
let URL_API_HOST2:String = "http://www.bla.com/MyImages/"
```

I want to combining  detailImage and URL_API_HOST2

And I want to show  combining  detailImage string like;

```
http://www.bla.com/MyImages/23423434.jpg
```

I need your help.
TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where your base url string is declared but I don't see why you couldn't simply concatenate the strings:

for example, instead of:

```
if let url = detailImage {
    load_image(url)
}
```

you can do

```
if let url = detailImage {
    load_image(URL_API_HOST2 + url)
}
```

Comment: WORKS ! Thank you very much dude ;)